# How to exclude in awk multiple non-alphanumeric characters using vars

Tags: regex, awk

I have defined a series of characters that I don't want to print.

In this example the character % is exclude correctly:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=";";ch1 = "%";ch2 = "-"}
{
if(NR > 1)
{
    if($1 !~ ch1)
    {
            print $1
    }
} 
}
END {}' $1
```

but when I add the second variable ch2 it doen't apply any of the filters:

See example below:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=";";ch1 = "%";ch2 = "-"}
{
if(NR > 1)
{
    if($1 !~ ch1|| $1 !~ ch2 )
    {
            print $1
    }
} 
}
END {}' $1
```

if either ch1 or ch2 is included in the first column I want the record to be excluded.

How can I accomplish that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have some reason to use a separate variable for each character:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=";"; ch1="%"; ch2="-"; badChars="["ch1 ch2"]"
}
(NR > 1) && ($1 !~ badChars) {
    print $1
} 
' "$1"
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `&&` instead of `||` because you want `$1` to not contain both characters:

```
if($1 !~ ch1 && $1 !~ ch2 )
```

Alternatively, you can use a bracket expression:

```
if ($1 !~ /[%-]/)
```

Comment: I already tried && but the seconds does't evaluate only the first var is filtered out

Answer (score 1):

Use and (&&) instead of or (||).

Now you only exclude the line if it contains both sequences.

Answer (score 0):

if bad characters breaks your awk code, then go for hex values. see below

```
> hexdump -C <<< "%-"
00000000  25 2d 0a                                          |%-.|
00000003
> awk -F"|" -v ch1="\x25" -v ch2="\x2d" ' $1~ch1 { print "yes %" } $2~ch2 { print "yes -"} ' <<< "abc%|def-|ghi"
yes %
yes -
>
```

**Explanation**

hexdump -C prints the hex value of the character.

In this example,  % to 25 and - to 2d.

Now you can pass this as -v argument to the awk code.